# Build Error on Xcode 15.3: "Called object type 'facebook::flipper::SocketCertificateProvider' is not a function or function pointer"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, flipper

I recently updated my Xcode to version 15.3 and encountered an issue while trying to build my React Native app on the simulator. The error message I'm receiving is:

**"Called object type 'facebook::flipper::SocketCertificateProvider' is not a function or function pointer."**

My react-native version is 0.71.8

Could someone please advise on how to resolve this error and successfully build my React Native app on Xcode 15.3?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution to this error.....

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/43335#issuecomment-1980285308

update...

1- from project navigator search about ==> FlipperTransportTypes

2- add this import ==> #include "functional"

3- save file and run again

Comment: I won't call it a solution, but more of a hack to make it build right now - the file is managed by CocoaPods so it needs to be changed after each pod install

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like the Flipper team is in a hurry to build releases of the new version tags mentioned and recommended in their documentation...

Comment: So @EsbenvonBuchwald what is now the right way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Add #include functional like the pic below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a CI/CD or need a CLI fix

Execute the following command inside your project.

```
if ! grep -q "#include <functional>" ./ios/Pods/Flipper/xplat/Flipper/FlipperTransportTypes.h; 
then
    chmod 755 ./ios/Pods/Flipper/xplat/Flipper/FlipperTransportTypes.h && sed -i '' 's|#include <string>|#include <functional>\n#include <string>|'  ./ios/Pods/Flipper/xplat/Flipper/FlipperTransportTypes.h
fi
```

then Clean and rebuild