# I am getting lots of errors when building react native app in Xcode

Tags: xcode, react-native, npm

I have got the code for a react native app, and want to publish this to appstore. After importing into Xcode, opening the ios folder I am running into over 200 Yellow warnings and 15 Red warning. I dont know if this means that there is an issue with react code or just how i have set it up. Currently the warning i am getting are attached below. How do i proceed to resolve them, and does this really matter if it cant build in Xcode given that i just want to upload to app store.

Thanks for any advice.[Yellow Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/st14h.png) and [Red Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyhnl.png)

I tried cleaning and rebuilding but still same errors

Comment: For your "Red Errors" you can refer this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78121217/build-error-on-xcode-15-3-called-object-type-facebookflippersocketcertifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78121217/build-error-on-xcode-15-3-called-object-type-facebookflippersocketcertifi)

Comment: For Yellow part, you can just ignore those. They are warnings that might related to your dependencies.